# Как перебрать таблицу в базе данных?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Имею базу данных `mysql`, и таблицу с большим количеством записей. Решил перебирать частями. Написал такой код:

```
async* _getEntities() {
    let offset = 0, total;
    const limit = 100;

    do {
        const result = //Запрос к базе данных. Limit и offset тоже тут указаны.

        //Рассчитываем смещение.
        offset = result.offset + limit;
        total = result.total;

        yield result.data;

    } while (offset < total);
}
```

И **контроллер** для этого такой:

```
async controller() {
   for await (const item of this._getEntities()) {
      if (тут условие) {
        //Запрос в базу данных, на удаление элемента. ТУТ И ЕСТЬ ПРОБЛЕМА.
      }
   }
}
```

Суть проблемы: если я удалю элемент, количество всех записей (`"total"`) изменится, a смещение (`offset`) это не учитывает, что приведет к пропускам.

Как корректно перебрать? Все, что пришло в голову - собрать массив с id и потом удалять.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (1) {
  ...
  if (!result.rows || result.rows.length < limit) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Но, вообще, нет смысла городить эту городушку так как в [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) есть команда `DELETE FROM TABLENAME WHERE ...YOUR_CONDITIONS...;`

Comment: Не, не получится. Тут, я, вероятно, не полностью описал условие, что проверяю в контроллере. Но mysql не сможет вызвать нейронку, проверить запись и вынести вердикт.

Comment: ну, хозяин-барин, хотя, если можно заранее вычислить критерий, который управляет удалением, возможно стоит его вычислять и хранить

Comment: Заранее тоже не выйдет, условие уникально для каждой записи. Также, вот это: `result.rows.length < limit` приведет к бесконечному циклу. Так как не все записи будут удалены из таблицы и если количество записей, что не попадают под условие удаления, превысит лимит, будет не очень.

Comment: ты не прав :) ты же offset-ом будешь двигать

Comment: Понял, в чем суть.

Comment: Только пропуски же будут: например, `total` 10, `offset` 5, и тут я удаляю пару записей. `total` 7, `offset` 5. Все ли элементы бд будут затронуты за одну итерацию?

Comment: primary key числовой?

Comment: Числовой, там id.

Comment: `select * from tablename where id > :last_known_id order by id limit :limit`